# How to delete a particular value from a datatable in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a datatable holding upto 20 values or more. Using selectrow statement

```
DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection selectedRows = dgvSelectedFieldsView.SelectedRows;
```

i have selected a row from the datatable now i need to delete that particular row from the datatable

can any one help me out

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Get the row that is selected
DataGridViewRow dr = selectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault();
//Your temp DataTable
DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
//If there is a row selected
if (dr != null)
{
  var rowToRemove = dtTemp.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().FirstOrDefault(row => row[0] == dr.Cells[0].Value);
  if (rowToRemove != null)
    dtTemp.Rows.Remove(rowToRemove);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for u r quick response @LukeHennerley ... I need to delete it from a temporary datatable  using the selected row ... is it possible

Comment: @Ganeshja depends if you have a `PrimaryKey` field.

Comment: yes i too have a primary key field @LukeHennerley .. can u provide me a sample of it please

Comment: @LukeHenneley Thanks a lot ... this will be useful for me