# How to delete a row from a datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

How to delete a row from a datatable_ Consider I have 12 rows in my data table, I need to delete one of them using particular row value ..

datatable :

```
Field Name | Field Type 
------------------------
FirstName  |  Text box
           |
LastName   |  Text box
```

I need to delete the selected row form the table itself 
using below code snippet I can retrieve  FirstName

```
string value = (string)selectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value;
Console.WriteLine(outdex);
```

But how delete it from the data table

Can any one help me out please?

Comment: Update your old question instead of asking a new one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247850/how-to-delete-a-particular-value-from-a-datatable-in-c-sharp/15248019?noredirect=1#comment21503697_15248019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the OP other question, he wants to get a selected row from a `DataGridView` and remove this row from a temporary `DataTable`.

```
//Get the row that is selected
DataGridViewRow dr = selectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault();
//Your temp DataTable
DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
//If there is a row selected
if (dr != null)
{
  var rowToRemove = dtTemp.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().FirstOrDefault(row => row[0] == dr.Cells[0].Value);
  if (rowToRemove != null)
    dtTemp.Rows.Remove(rowToRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
       .Where(r => r.ItemArray[0] == "Any_Value")
       .ToList()
       .ForEach(r => r.Delete());
```

OR

```
DataView view = new DataView(dt);
view.RowFilter = "Column_name = 10";

foreach (DataRowView row in view)
{
  row.Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code,

```
  var rows = dataTable.Select("condition to select");
    rows.ForEach((r) => r.Delete(););
    dataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value == "some deleteValue")
    selectedRows[i].Delete();
```

If doing this in a loop though, you'd want something more like this answer though:
[Deleting specific rows from DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648339/deleting-specific-rows-from-datatable)